# rails s command is starting the wrong application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bit of a strange problem. I'm in ~/My Programs/app2. I run 'rails s' and it starts the application located in ~/My Programs/app1 on localhost:3000. Any idea why this might be happening?

No error messages..

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that your server for app1 is still running

try `rails s -p 4000`

and go to localhost:4000 that should bring you to your app

Remove rails detached server by using command

`ps -aef | grep rails`
OR by this command

`lsof -wni tcp:3000`
then

`kill -9 pID`

Comment: I am a moron. Thank you :)

Comment: If anyone comes across this in the future, all I had to do was close my other terminal tab where rails s was already running for app1.

Comment: @DrewSkrainka What is your web server ? Puma or WEBrick or anything else ? And, were both the server running on same port `3000` ?

Comment: @DrewSkrainka you are not such thing, the only reason I know this is because it happens to me all the time :)